# How do I use Dash Pages to render tab content in Plotly Dash?

Tags: python

I’m trying to use Dash Pages with a Tabbed page format. I have followed the Plotly Dash documentation and am sure my folder structure is correct: app.py in main folder and three .py files in a pages folder. I’m sure the pages files are correctly formatted because they are from the Dash Coordinator's GitHub.

Typically:

```
import dash
from dash import dcc, html
import plotly.express as px

dash.register_page(name, path=‘/’)

df = px.data.gapminder()

layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Dropdown([x for x in df.continent.unique()], id=‘cont-choice’, style={‘width’:‘50%’}),
        dcc.Graph(id=‘line-fig’,
        figure=px.histogram(df, x=‘continent’, y=‘lifeExp’, histfunc=‘avg’))
    ]
)
```

When I load the app the home page ('/') renders but when I change tab the new content doesn't load.

I just cannot seem to get the link between app.py and the pages file to work correctly. Here’s the code I m using:

```
import dash
from dash import html, dcc, callback, Input, Output

app = dash.Dash(name, use_pages=True)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Div(“Python Multipage App with Dash”, style={‘fontSize’:50, ‘textAlign’:‘center’}),

        dcc.Tabs(id='tabs', value='tab-1', children=[
        dcc.Tab(label='Tab one', value='tab-1'),
        dcc.Tab(label='Tab two', value='tab-2')
    ]),

    # content of each page
    dash.page_container    
    ], id='mainDiv'
)

@callback(
Output(‘mainDiv’, ‘children’),
Input(‘tabs’, ‘value’)
)
def render_content(tab):
    if tab == ‘tab-1’:
        return html.Div(dcc.Link(href=dash.page_registry[‘pages./’][‘path’]), refresh=True)
    if tab == ‘tab-2’:
        return html.Div(dcc.Link(href=dash.page_registry[‘pages.pg2’][‘path’]), refresh=True)

if name == “main”:
    app.run(debug=True, port=8001)
```

I’m sure I don't have a full grasp of how Dash Pages work and I’m missing something. Can anyone help? Thanks!